# How to require a json key to be present but allow the value to be null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a model with a nullable double in my API, I want anyone posting to it to be required to include the key in the json body. I am using the [FromBody] to receive the data from the json in the post function.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate it with the required attribute https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute

or do a check in the controller for the property and if it’s null return BadRequest

Comment: This doesn't allow it to be explicitly set to null in the json.